# Accessing Search Results from Online Public Database using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, web, search, public

I have to access e-court data from NC based on docket numbers available in a dataset obtained from a public request. The website https://portal-nc.tylertech.cloud/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29 allows me to search for records based on a docket number. The api is the URL for the public search website; Search includes the items that appear in the "payload" tab of the source code when I ran the search.

I am searching for any docket number starting with "17CR0*" in Wake County, public records of criminal and infraction, between 01/01/2017 and 12/31/2017.

I was expecting a list similar to the online results but longer since the online page was limited to 200 rows.

I got the following error message when I ran the code, despite getting results when I searched the online database.

> Response [https://portal-nc.tylertech.cloud/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29]
> Date: 2023-11-05 00:14
> Status: 403
> Content-Type: 
>
> NULL

Can you help me figure out what is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

api_url <- "https://portal-nc.tylertech.cloud/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29" 

search <- list(
  caseCriteria.searchCriteria="17CR0*", 
  caseCriteria.CourtLocation="Wake County",
  caseCriteria.CaseType="All Public Records",
  caseCriteria.CaseType_input="Criminal+and+Infraction",
  caseCriteria.FileDateStart="01/01/2017",
  caseCriteria.FileDateEnd="12/31/2017"
)

response <- POST(api_url, body=search , encode = "form", verbose())
```

Comment: APIs are not just parameterized URLs. Is there actual documentation of an API with this data source?

Comment: Any well designed API is also going to limit the number of responses per request and force you to make multiple requests if you want more.  Also data mining is prohibited by rthe Terms of Service. https://www.nccourts.gov/legal-notices-disclaimers-and-terms-of-use#data-mining-spiders-and-high-volume-page-access-1228

Comment: @elin  Thanks for your feedback. I have a login to access the site, I have permission to search and access the online database. I am accessing information for a specific timeframe not extracting a volume of data with mining tools.

Comment: @Parfait I will ask if such information is available.

Comment: Great!
Normally the number of cases is limited, one way or another, and then you have to make multiple requests more or less looping through the pages.